# UI does not update when the React component re-renders

Tags: reactjs

I have a "PlayerItem" component which is a child of the "PlayerList" component, which in turn is a child of the "UserPlayers" component. The UserPlayers component contains a function that is called via props from the "PlayerItem" component to render the UserPlayers component. The component renders correctly when I update the state (whenever I submit a bid for a player), but the UI button that is conditionally set to display one way or the other does not update until I exit the page and re-enter. I think it's a bit of a confusing explanation and I'm also new to react, so I'm attaching here a video of the problem:

https://youtu.be/qQxSHuTbxXg

What I want to achieve is that when I bid on the player, it stays on the page but the button should change to "edit bid".

UserPlayers.js:

```
const UserPlayers = () => {
  const [loadedPlayers, setLoadedPlayers] = useState();
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const userId = useParams().userId;
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlayers = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/players/user/${userId}`
        );
        setLoadedPlayers(responseData.players);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchPlayers();
  }, [sendRequest, userId]);

  const playerDeletedHandler = (deletedPlayerId) => {
    setLoadedPlayers((prevPlayers) =>
      prevPlayers.filter((player) => player.id !== deletedPlayerId)
    );
  };

  const updateHandler = () => {
    if (update === false) {
      setUpdate(true);
    } else {
      setUpdate(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
      <Presupuesto></Presupuesto>
      {isLoading && (
        <div className="center">
          <LoadingSpinner />
        </div>
      )}
      {!isLoading && loadedPlayers && (
        <PlayerList
          items={loadedPlayers}
          onDeletePlayer={playerDeletedHandler}
          onUpdate={updateHandler}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default UserPlayers;
```

PlayerList.js:

```
    const PlayerList = (props) => {
      if (props.items.length === 0) {
        return (
          <div className="place-list center">
            <Card>
              <h2>Players not found</h2>
              <Button to="/players/new">Share Player</Button>
            </Card>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return (
        <ul className="place-list">
          {props.items.map((player) => (
            <PlayerItem
              key={player.id}
              id={player.id}
              image={player.image}
              title={player.title}
              clausula={player.clausula}
              address={player.address}
              creatorId={player.creator}
              Expires={player.Expires}
              ofertas={player.ofertas}
              onDelete={props.onDeletePlayer}
              onUpdate={props.onUpdate}
            ></PlayerItem>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    };
    
    export default PlayerList;
```

PlayerItem.js:

```
const PlayerItem = (props) => {
  const addingMiliseconds = 12096e5;
  const ahora = Date.now();
  const history = useHistory();
  const playerId = props.id;
  const [formState, inputHandler] = useForm(
    {
      cantidad: {
        value: "",
        isValid: false,
      },
    },
    false
  );
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [loadedOfertas, setLoadedOfertas] = useState();
  const [showConfirmOfertaModal, setShowConfirmOfertaModal] = useState(false);
  const [showVerOfertasModal, setShowVerOfertasModal] = useState(false);
  const [showSubirClausulaModal, setShowSubirClausulaModal] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmModal, setShowConfirmModal] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmClausulaModal, setShowConfirmClausulaModal] =
    useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOfertas = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/ofertas/player/${playerId}`
        );
        setLoadedOfertas(responseData.ofertas);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchOfertas();
  }, [sendRequest, playerId]);
  const openVerOfertasHandler = () => {
    setShowVerOfertasModal(true);
  };
  const closeVerOfertasHandler = () => setShowVerOfertasModal(false);
  const openOfertaHandler = () => setShowConfirmOfertaModal(true);

  const cancelDeleteHandler = () => {
    setShowConfirmModal(false);
  };

  const cancelOfertaHandler = () => {
    setShowConfirmOfertaModal(false);
    setShowSubirClausulaModal(false);
  };

  const confirmOfertaHandler = async () => {
    setShowConfirmOfertaModal(false);
    try {
      await sendRequest(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/ofertas",
        "POST",
        JSON.stringify({
          cantidad: Number(formState.inputs.cantidad.value),
          ofertanteId: auth.userId,
          playerId: props.id,
          equipoOfertante: auth.userTeam,
          nombreOfertante: auth.userName,
          escudoOfertante: auth.userImage,
        }),
        { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      );
      props.onUpdate();
      //history.push("/");
    } catch (err) {}
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError}></ErrorModal>
            {auth.isLoggedIn && auth.userId !== props.creatorId && (
              <Button onClick={openOfertaHandler}>
                {loadedOfertas &&
                loadedOfertas.filter(
                  (oferta) => oferta.ofertanteId === auth.userId
                ).length > 0
                  ? "EDITAR OFERTA"
                  : "HACER OFERTA"}
              </Button>
            )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default PlayerItem;
```

Comment: Hi There! I was reading your code and I think it would be much easier if you could create something like a code snippet. Anyway some improvements you can do in the meantime: 

  const updateHandler = () => {
    if (update === false) {
      setUpdate(true);
    } else {
      setUpdate(false);
    }
  };

can be change to  const updateHandler = () => setUpdate(!update);

just to Let you know, <React.Fragment> </React.Fragment> === <></>

I cannot see loadedOfertas anywhere but the button, is that the whole code?
I think the problem can be there.

Comment: Last: Work with 1 language, you are mixing Spanish with english. it is easier long term if you just work in English :D

Comment: Thank you for your advice. "loadedOffers" is in the "PlayerItem" component, which descends from the "PlayerList" component.

Comment: I see, can you put the confirm modal logic? I think you are not re render because of the watchers you put on the useEffect ([sendRequest, playerId]) maybe if you add the showConfirmOfertaModal and check if the value is false, you are going to re-fetch the array and have the new info there. This could be a solution, not necessary the best way of doing it. Maybe analyze using redux, or any state management system (apollo maybe? with the CACHE system)

Comment: I just added the update state as a dependency into the useEffect watcher from the UserPlayers component and now all is working fine. At the moment I will go ahead with this solution. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I will write here the answer that worked for you.

The missing point was the dependency on the useEffect to re-fetch the information when confirming the modal.
Probably something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOfertas = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/ofertas/player/${playerId}`
        );
        setLoadedOfertas(responseData.ofertas);
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    if (!!sendRequest && playerId && !showConfirmOfertaModal) {
        fetchOfertas();
    }

  }, [sendRequest, playerId, showConfirmOfertaModal]);
```

The problem was not having the updated information after the POST for adding the offer.